# binary semaphore to synchronize threads in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, semaphore

everyone.
I am new to semaphore and recently I am learning to implement a simple problem using binary semaphores and i have some questions.

So there is a visiting room, at one time only one person can go in. In my design there are three queues of people (which are all the threads i created). For example, after the person in the second queue visited that room, the next person who is going to enter the room is the top one waiting in third queue, rather the first queue's person. The number of total people is given. and after leaving, just simply terminate the thread.

I am trying to create three semaphores to handle this, i.e, after one person in second queue enters, then block the second queue and ONLY "signal" the third queue to continue. and so on so forth. However, the code has some problems. here I just show some semaphore part of code.

int the main:

sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);

sem_init(&s0, 0, 1);

sem_init(&s1, 0, 1);

sem_init(&s2, 0, 1);

// create 100 pthread and randomly put into queue0 or queue1 or queue2

```
 for(int i = 0; i<num_thread; i++){ 

        pthread_t curr_thread;
        if(queueId == 0){
            queue0.push(curr_thread);           
        }else if(queueId == 1){ 
            queue1.push(curr_thread);   
        }else if(queueId == 2){ 
            queue2.push(curr_thread);   
        }
            pthread_attr_t attr;
            pthread_attr_init (&attr);
            pthread_attr_setdetachstate (&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
            pthread_create (&curr_thread, &attr, &thread_function, &queue_Num);
            pthread_attr_destroy (&attr);

    }
```

in the thread function:

```
void* thread_function (void* arg){

        sem_wait(&mutex);

        int n = *((int*) arg);
        if(n==0){
            sem_wait(&s0);
            cout << "person in queue" << n << " is visiting" << endl;
            sleep(1);
            if(!queue0.empty()){
                queue0.pop();
            }else{
                n++;
            }
            sem_post(&s1);

        }else if(n==1){
            sem_wait(&s1);
            cout << "person in queue" << n << " is visiting" << endl;
            sleep(1);
            if(!queue1.empty()){
                queue1.pop();
            }else{
                n++;
            }
            sem_post(&s2);
        }else if(n==2){
            sem_wait(&s2);
            cout << "person in queue" << n << " is visiting" << endl;
            sleep(1);
            if(!queue2.empty()){
                queue2.pop();
            }else{
                n++;
            }
            sem_post(&s0);
        }

        sem_post(&mutex);

    return NULL;
}
```

Actually when I run it, seems like I met "deadlock", the main finished with showing only 2 threads every time. I thought there must be some problems in the designing of the thread_function. Is there anybody can help point it out and tell me how to fix it? Thanks advance.

Comment: Try putting a print statement before you wait, and tell me what you see.

Comment: It simply blocks , showing only one thread is visiting, then the main is done. i am just wondering is there any problem with the design of the thread_function?

Comment: How are your `queueId` and `queue_Num` defined?

Comment: the queueid is the tag to differentiate the different queues. (so if queue id = 0, that means the first queue which is queue0, so on so forth) the queue_Num is queueId, i typed wrong.

Comment: I mean like, how is it calculated/set? Regardless, I think I know what your problem is.

Comment: em.. I randomly create a number between 0 to 3 as the queueid, then put thread randomly in the three queues. I thought it is a problem of designing semaphores,, the printing result shows that it definitely met the deadlocks..

Comment: Perhaps you should post more of your `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass your `queueId` to the threads, you don't want to pass it a pointer to one of your local variables, because you are going to be changing that very quickly. You should instead just be passing in the integer itself to your threads:

```
pthread_create(&curr_thread, &attr, &thread_function, (void*)queueId);
                                        // Pass queueId the int, not a pointer
```

Then, when you need to read the value in your threads, just cast the `void*` back to an integer:

```
void* thread_function (void* arg){
    ...

    int n = (long)arg;

    ..
}
```

After this, your code works great, for me.

Comment: The output only shows "person1 is visiting", then program is finished ... what are the status of other threads? i  created 10 threads for testing, and it should pop up 10 times telling me which person goes in.. em.. or can you leave your contact, maybe email address, i can send the code to you to have a look